# Frequency of each string from given list

Tags: python, string, count

i want to calculate frequency of each unique word from a given list. for eg. Input list = ['kasol', 'kasol', 'manali', 'delhi', 'delhi', 'manali, 'kasol']

Output = 
kasol - 3
manali - 2
delhi - 2

i tried

```
def frequency(a, x):
    count = 0


for i in a:
    if i == x: count += 1
return count
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter:

```
L = ['elt1', 'elt1', 'elt2', 'elt2', 'elt3', 'elt4', 'elt5']
from collections import Counter
Counter(L)
Out: Counter({'elt1': 2, 'elt2': 2, 'elt3': 1, 'elt4': 1, 'elt5': 1})
```